# Import sbt and typesafe in build (IntelliJ)

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

i can't import the sbt and typesafe libraries into build.sbt in IntelliJ.

The dependencies of sbt and typesafe are in the plugin.sbt file. In the file plugin.sbt also I have the addSbtPlugin method in red:

[plugin.sbt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42dGY.png)

while the import of the libraries are inside the build.sbt file.

[build.sbt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJxRc.png)

My

How can I do?

**Update**

The `build.sbt` file is this:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.license.{DepModuleInfo, LicenseCategory, LicenseInfo}
import sbt._
import scala.io.Source

// Core library versions (the ones that are used multiple times)
val sparkVersion: String = "2.3.1"
val slf4jVersion: String = "1.7.25"
val logbackVersion: String = "1.2.3"

// Artifactory settings
val artifactoryRealm: String = "artifactory-espoo1.int.net.nokia.com"
val artifactoryUrl: String = s"https://$artifactoryRealm/artifactory/"
val artifactoryUser: Option[String] = sys.env.get("ARTIFACTORY_USER")
val artifactoryPassword: Option[String] = sys.env.get("ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD")

// Project variables
val organizationId: String = "com.nokia.gs.npo.ae"
val rootPackage: String = organizationId + ".rfco"

// Base settings shared across modules
val baseSettings: Seq[SettingsDefinition] = Seq(
  organization := organizationId,
  version := Source.fromFile(file("VERSION")).mkString.trim + sys.env.getOrElse("VERSION_TAG", ""),
  scalaVersion := "2.11.12",
  buildInfoUsePackageAsPath := true,
  scalafmtOnCompile in ThisBuild := false, // just invoke `sbt scalafmt` before commits!
  parallelExecution in ThisBuild := false,
  fork in Test := true,
  testForkedParallel in Test := true,
  logLevel in test := util.Level.Info,
  coverageMinimum := sys.env.getOrElse("COVERAGE_MINIMUM", "80.0").toDouble,
  coverageFailOnMinimum := true,
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.apache.spark"              %% "spark-sql"               % sparkVersion   % Provided,
    "org.apache.spark"              %% "spark-hive"              % sparkVersion   % Provided,
    "org.slf4j"                     % "slf4j-api"                % slf4jVersion   % Compile,
    "com.nokia.gs.ncs.chubs.common" %% "spark-commons"           % "0.5.10"       % Compile,
    "com.nokia.gs.ncs.chubs.common" %% "lang"                    % "0.2.0"        % Compile,
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.module"  %% "jackson-module-scala"    % "2.9.8"        % Compile,
    "com.typesafe.play"             %% "play-json"               % "2.7.1"        % Compile,
    "org.apache.commons"            % "commons-csv"              % "1.7"          % Compile,
    "org.scalatest"                 %% "scalatest"               % "3.0.5"        % Test,
    "ch.qos.logback"                % "logback-classic"          % logbackVersion % Test,
    "ch.qos.logback"                % "logback-core"             % logbackVersion % Test,
    "org.apache.spark"              %% "spark-hive-thriftserver" % sparkVersion   % Test,
    "com.github.tomakehurst"        % "wiremock-standalone"      % "2.22.0"       % Test
  ),
  excludeDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala",
    "org.slf4j"                    % "slf4j-log4j12",
    "org.hamcrest"                 % "hamcrest-core",
    "javax.servlet"                % "servlet-api"
  ),
  publishTo := {
    Some("Artifactory Realm" at artifactoryUrl + sys.env.getOrElse("ARTIFACTORY_LOCATION", "ava-maven-snapshots-local"))
  },
  packagedArtifacts in publish ~= { m =>
    val classifiersToExclude = Set(Artifact.SourceClassifier)
    m.filter({ case (art, _) => art.classifier.forall(c => !classifiersToExclude.contains(c)) })
  },
  (artifactoryUser, artifactoryPassword) match {
    case (Some(user), Some(password)) =>
      credentials += Credentials("Artifactory Realm", artifactoryRealm, user, password)
    case _ =>
      println("[info] USERNAME and/or PASSWORD is missing for publishing to Artifactory")
      credentials := Seq()
  }
)
```

Comment: Looks like you're using `Build.scala` syntax in a `build.sbt` flie. Also, where are these two files located? `build.sbt` should be in your project root folder. `plugins.sbt` should be located inside a `project` folder.

Comment: The `build.sbt` is located in root folder. `plugin.sbt` is located in `project` folder. Which syntax should I use? I run the command from terminal `sbt compile`

Comment: Have a look at https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Basic-Def.html

Comment: Plus in your build.sbt I only see some version numbers (for spark, slf4j etc...). What are the artifacts you need? usually you have something like `libraryDependencies ++= Seq(  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.25"...`

Comment: the build.sbt file is very long. Some dependencies in the build.sbt file are these:

 `libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.apache.spark"              %% "spark-sql"               % sparkVersion   % Provided,
    "org.apache.spark"              %% "spark-hive"              % sparkVersion   % Provided
    )`

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the `build.sbt` your `plugins.sbt` should at least contain these lines:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-license-report" % "1.2.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n"     % "sbt-buildinfo"      % "0.9.0")
addSbtPlugin("org.scalameta"    % "sbt-scalafmt"       % "2.2.1")
addSbtPlugin("org.scoverage"    % "sbt-scoverage"      % "1.6.1")
```

Comment: In the build.sbt I have to import import sbt:

```
    import sbt._
    name := "My Project"

    version := "1.0"

    scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.1"
```

Comment: You shouldn't. What version of sbt are you using?

Comment: Have a look https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Migrating-from-sbt-013x.html#Migrating+from+the+Build+trait

Comment: `sbt.version=1.3.8`

Comment: I see. Still I think you first need to decide if you want `Build.scala` or `build.sbt`. In more recent versions of sbt `Build.scala` definitions are deprecated.

Comment: i want to use `build.sbt`

Comment: Follow the suggestions here https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Migrating-from-sbt-013x.html#Migrating+from+the+Build+trait

1. Rename project/Build.scala to build.sbt.
2. Remove import statements import sbt._, import Keys._, and any auto imports.
etc...

Comment: I already have the build.sbt file. The link you sent me instead explains how to migrate from build.scala to build.sbt

Comment: Then I'm not sure what your issue is. If you post the whole content of your sbt file, maybe I can have a look.

Comment: I changed my answer

Answer (score 0):

I solved import sbt, creating a new project on IntelliJ IDea and importing the source files into the project I created. Oddly now it does the import. Before, however, I opened the source folder with the code from IntelliJ, but not made the import of sbt.

[build.sbt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nc5Tz.png)

I only have to resolve type safe dependencies, but it is a problem with external and private dependencies.

Thanks for your help